# Can we use cglib compiled with java 8 on jdk 11.0.3?

Tags: java, java-8, out-of-memory, java-11, cglib

`Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`
`at net.sf.cglib.asm.$SymbolTable.put(SymbolTable.java:410)`
`at net.sf.cglib.asm.$SymbolTable.addConstantUtf8(SymbolTable.java:775)`
`at net.sf.cglib.asm.$FieldWriter.<init>(FieldWriter.java:130)`
`at net.sf.cglib.asm.$ClassWriter.visitField(ClassWriter.java:387)`
`at net.sf.cglib.asm.$ClassVisitor.visitField(ClassVisitor.java:287)`
`at net.sf.cglib.core.ClassEmitter.declare_field(ClassEmitter.java:192)`
`at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptorGenerator.generate(MethodInterceptorGenerator.java:95)`
`at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitMethods(Enhancer.java:1219)`
`at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:630)`
`at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)`
`at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:332)`
`at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492)`
`at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)`
`at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)`
`at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)`
`at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)`
`at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)`
`at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)`
`at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)`
`at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)`
`at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480)`
`at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:305)`

cglib was working fine with java 8 but facing OOM error with java 11. Here are the memory settings

`JAVA_XMS="-Xms512m"`

`JAVA_XMX="-Xmx2G"`

`JAVA_PERM="-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m"`

I have tried increasing the heap space upto 8GB but still getting the OOM error.

Comment: You can compile code under Java 8 and run it under Java 11 without problems. But when you let a bytecode processing library read Java 11 class files, the library must be up-to-date to be able to handle these newer class files. It’s not clear whether this OOME is a symptom of an inability to parse newer class files, but at least, you should check whether your version of cglib is specified to be JDK 11 compatible.

Comment: Yeah i have tried using the latest cglib version 3.3.0, was getting the same OOME

Comment: You could try to run with `-Dcglib.useCache=false` to see whether there’s an issue with the cache.